# Weighting a String Distance Metric based on regular expressions

Tags: r

Is it possible to weight a string distance metric such as the Damerau-Levenshtein distance where the weight changes based on the character type?

I am looking to create a fuzzy match of addresses and need to weight numbers and letters differently so that an address like:

**"5 James Street"** and **"5 Jmaes Street"** are considered **identical** and

**"5 James Street"** and **"6 James Street"** are considered **different**.

I considered splitting the addresses into numbers and letters prior to applying the string distance however this will miss flats at **"5a"** and **"5b"**. The ordering is also not consistent amongst the data set so one entry may be **"James Street 5"**.

I am using R with the stringdist package currently but not restricted to these.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered trying a geocoding API for this project?

Comment: @AndrewBrēza Thank you for the suggestion. I did think about this but wanted to still match an address that may be inappropriately written that an API wouldn't pick up. For example ***"5#Jam#es Str$eet"*** to still match, sorry for not being more specific here!

Comment: The Google Maps API should still be able to recognize misspelled place names. When I search for 5#Jam#es Str$eet in Google Maps the correct location appears in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. It involves a bit of manual processing but it might be a good starting point. First, we compute the approximate string distance between the addresses using `adist()` (or `stringdist()` with the best suited `method` to your data) without paying attention to street numbers.

```
m <- adist(v) 
rownames(m) <- v

> m
#                     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#5 James Street          0    2    3    1    4   17   17
#5 Jmaes Street          2    0    4    3    6   17   17
#5#Jam#es Str$eet        3    4    0    4    6   17   17
#6 James Street          1    3    4    0    4   17   17
#James Street 5          4    6    6    4    0   16   17
#10a Cold Winter Road   17   17   17   17   16    0    1
#10b Cold Winter Road   17   17   17   17   17    1    0
```

In this case, we can clearly identify the two clusters, but we could also use `hclust()` to visualize a dendrogram.

```
cl <- hclust(as.dist(m))
plot(cl)
rect.hclust(cl, 2)
```

[image]

Then, we tag each street to it's corresponding cluster of similarities, iterate through them and check for matching street numbers.

```
library(dplyr)
res <- data.frame(cluster = cutree(cl, 2)) %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("address") %>%
  mutate(
    # Extract all components of the address
    lst = stringi::stri_extract_all_words(address),
    # Identify the component containing the street number and return it
    num = purrr::map_chr(lst, .f = ~ grep("\\d+", .x, value = TRUE))) %>% 
  # For each cluster, tag matching street numbers
  mutate(group = group_indices_(., .dots = c("cluster", "num")))
```

Which gives:

```
#               address cluster                     lst num group
#1       5 James Street       1        5, James, Street   5     1
#2       5 Jmaes Street       1        5, Jmaes, Street   5     1
#3     5#Jam#es Str$eet       1    5, Jam, es, Str, eet   5     1
#4       6 James Street       1        6, James, Street   6     2
#5       James Street 5       1        James, Street, 5   5     1
#6 10a Cold Winter Road       2 10a, Cold, Winter, Road 10a     3
#7 10b Cold Winter Road       2 10b, Cold, Winter, Road 10b     4
```

You could then `pull()` the unique addresses based on `group` using `distinct()`:

```
> distinct(res, group, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% pull(address)
#[1] "5 James Street"       "6 James Street"       "10a Cold Winter Road"
#    "10b Cold Winter Road"
```

---

**Data**

```
v <- c("5 James Street", "5 Jmaes Street", "5#Jam#es Str$eet", "6 James Street",
       "James Street 5", "10a Cold Winter Road", "10b Cold Winter Road")
```

Comment: That is a great suggestion Steven. Its a great base to use. I think adist will a miss a few matchings but I can use a couple of the string dist metrics to capture them! Thanks!